# Using open.window() to open js program in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have a program that is written in CSS/HTML/JavaScript all inline, and opened directly from the HTML file (no web URL). Right now, everyone I work with has their browser set to open any links in a new tab in the same window, which makes the program useless, as it is form that is filled out manually, meant to be on a second monitor.

Right now, I have the `window.resizeTo();` and the `window.moveTo();` functions working properly IF the open in tabs is changed to open links in new window, but I cant walk around doing that to over 500 computers (no exaggeration on the amount), not to mention, any changes to the settings are reset afte the computers are reset.

When I try the `window.open();`, it just opens up a blank page in a new window after the .html file is opened, I need it to open itself in a new window, and then resize/move after.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your prompt answers! I feel I may have been confusing with what I need though. If I am to use the "window.open('my_file.html');" , It just sets an endless look up constantly openeing itself over and over again. I need it to actually open just itself up in a new window, and not in a tab for internet explorer 8. As clarification, I ONLY need this to work with internet explorer 8, as that is the only possible browser to use at my work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.open(...)` with the height and width parameters set. This will force the link to open in a new window:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">Share Page</a>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ay2GY/)**

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean, but this file is not opened with a link. It is opened from the desktop, as if it was a standalone program. I need it to place itself in its own window upon opening.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a URL to `window.open()` to open that URL.
You can pass the current URL using `location.href`.

You can also specify a size and location directly in the third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a page on tab or a separate window is browser specify feature, and it cannot be controlled by a Web Application.

`window.open()` will open a `popup` window and can open any URL you specify when provided:

```
window.open('openthispage.html);
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)`

add the URL of the program and it should work